# What does "Non-Mfg Zoom Lens" mean?

Tags: lens, terminology

When I was surfing [keh](http://keh.com) I found "Non-Mfg Zoom Lenses" and "Non-Mfg Fixed Focal Length Lenses"? What is the meaning of "Non-Mfg"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's short for "non-manufacturer". Of course, all lenses have a manufacturer — you can't grow them on trees! — but the expression means that the lens manufacturer is different from the company that makes the cameras the lens is designed for.

This is also known as "third party" (the "first party" being the company and the "second party" being you — or maybe the other way around; in any case "third" is definitely some *other* company).

If you're looking for lenses for Pentax K mount, for example, lenses made by Tamron, Tokina, or Sigma would be in the "non-mfg" category.

Answer (score 6):

They mean zoom lenses or prime lenses not made by the manufacturer of the camera. In other words, a third party lens manufacturer. Examples would be Sigma, Tokina, and Tamron. They produce lenses for Nikon and Canon cameras (among others).